# How to find euro zone equivalent of treasury data in U.S. using FinancialData?

Tags: curated-data, finance

For example I use `FinancialData["^TYX", "Price", {{2004}, {2014}, "Week"}];` to get data for U.S. treasury data, can I do the same for eurozone yield curve? I know I can import the data from [here](https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/money/yc/html/index.en.html) and then to *Mathematica*, but I would like to do it directly as described above.

Comment: It seems this data is no longer available as of v13.1